# download xml file using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have created a xml file using c# and I can save it at any location in my machine (in this situation I have saved it on the root of the application with name "temp.xml"), but I want to let it for the user to download it from their browser buy giving a link like-->
"click HERE to download the file."

In Chrome and FireFox it show a new tab with only some values in my body part of the xml file but IE shows the whole xml. I want to download it in my download folder when anybody click on the above link.

thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically mention the file type and name. and use the TransmitFile method. This will show the `Save As` window.

I got the following code from [this webpage](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET)

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/images/sailbig.jpg") );
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, when I tried the following code it gives me error

base {System.Exception} = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: Try using the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead of `Response.End()` method. I have updated the question. And no need to call me Sir! :)

Comment: thanks for the time. actually I am using WebMethod and it is static so its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=temp.xml");
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Write(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/temp.xml"))); //you may want to write the XML directly to output stream instead of creating an XML file first.
Response.End();
```

Hope this helps.